# How to call a function?

Tags: python

So here's my problem. I am creating a telephone directory in python 3.3.2, and I need to know how to call seperate functions. Here is my code:

```
details = {"Toby": "123", "James": "234", "Paul": "345"}

print("Welcome To The Telephone Directory.\n")

print("To search out specific details, please type Search.\n To add a new person to the Directory, type Add.\n To change someone's details, please type Edit.")

search = input();

if(input() == search.strip() in "search Search SEARCH".split()):

    def search():

        print("Please enter the name of the customer.")
        customer = input()
        print("Number:" ,details.get(customer))
        if(customer not in details):
             print("I'm sorry, but the person you defined is not in the directory.")


flag = True
while flag:
    search()
    flag = input("Would you like to look up another person? [Y/N]") == "y"

if(input() == add.strip() in "add Add ADD".split()):
    def add():

        print("Please enter the name of the new entry.")
        name = input()
        print("Now enter the entry's phone number.")
        telNumber = input()
        details[name] = telNumber
        print("You have succesfully added a new entry:\n",name,"\n",telNumber)
```

So I need to know how to call the Add function right from the start.

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot assign in a expression, so `if(input() == search.strip() in "search Search SEARCH".split()):` is **not** doing what you think it does.

Comment: You call a function by `function_name(arguments)`, but that's not the biggest problem with this code at the moment.

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: "How to call a function" is described in the official tutorial, and in any other reasonable text, long before you get to things like "how to define a function". For example, if you just get through [An Informal Introduction to Python](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html), it will show you how to do this about half-way through the page.

Answer (score 1):

you are defining functions inside of If statements that are never actually getting called

you want something like this:

```
def do_definition(x): #defining your function, before you call it
    print(x)

y = 'foo'
if statement:
    do_definition(y) # this is actually calling the function
```

Usually when you are starting off you want to define your functions first at the top, and then call them in other places

also i think you may want to check your syntax.

When you are making `search = input()` ( you dont need a semi colon after it btw ), and then you later on call `search()` this technically means you are calling `input()()` which is weird.

plus, if you move the `def search():` stuff out of the `if` statement, you are using another variable called `search` in your code, which will cause confusion in life.